# Is there a way to ensure atomicity while having a multithreaded program with signal handlers?

Tags: c, signals, posix, mutex, atomic

If I have a program like this (in pseudocode):

```
mutex_lock;
func() {
    lock(mutex_lock);
    // Some code (long enough to make a
    // race condition if no proper synchronisation
    // is available). We also going to call a signal,
    // say, SIGINT, through (ctrl-c), while we are in
    // the range of locking and unlocking the lock.
    unlock(mutex_lock);
}

sig_handler_func(sig) {
    // Say, we are handling SIGINT (ctrl-c) signal
    // And we need to call func from here too.
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        func();
    }
}

main() {
    // Calling func from main
    func();
}
```

then there would be a deadlock when trying to acquire the lock in func, while it is already acquired from the 'main' caller. I was wondering if there is a way to suspend the signal handling in the C language, specifically, when, in this example, entering func and acquiring the lock, and resume the signal handling AND call the handlers upon exiting func.

Comment: The interaction between threads and signal handling in C itself is undefined. You need to be more specific. Is your system a POSIX system? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `pthread_sigmask`, the multithread version of `sigprocmask`

Here's some sample pseudo code:

```
int
main(void)
{
    sigset_t omask;
    sigset_t nmask;

    // add as many signals as you want to the mask ...
    sigemptyset(&nmask);
    sigaddset(&nmask,SIGINT);

    // [temporarily] block signals
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK,&nmask,&omask);

    // call function safely
    func();

    // restore signal mask
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK,&omask,NULL);

    // pending signals should occur now ...
}
```

I'm not totally sure, but, you may need to use `pthread_sigmask` to block signals in all but *one* thread and do the above from that thread only.

Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't say that I'd refactor your code. The number of things you can do in a signal handler [aside from this] is limited (e.g. no `malloc`, no `printf`, etc.)

Dedicating one thread for signal handling and having it do `sigsetjmp` and the signal handler does `siglongjmp`.

Or have the signal handler set a volatile global (e.g. `signal_occurred`) that is monitored at base level.

Thus, all the "heavy lifting" that you'd be doing in the signal handler can be done from base task level where you can do anything.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend against `siglongjmp()`ing into a `sigjmp_buf` created by another thread's `sigsetjmp()`.

Comment: But, after pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK,&omask,NULL), would I still call the signal handler for the pending signals?? or they have to be called once again??

Comment: @EOF Of course. My first line was about blocking signals in all but _one_ thread [and that's where the `sigsetjmp/siglongjmp` would be done]. And I said: "Dedicating one thread for signal handling and having _it_ do sigsetjmp and the signal handler does siglongjmp". Personally, I prefer [and have used] the volatile global [or equivalent] approach.

Comment: After the signals are unblocked, they will occur just as if you had never blocked them in the first place. So, no need to manually call the signal handler [which you can't really anyway, because you can't set up the special signal handler context]. It will be called for you [in the _special_ way that signal handlers are always called]. Note the last comment line in the example code. What else [besides the mutex] is `func` doing? I've done this sort of thing for production mission-critical realtime systems and I, again, wish to stress there is a probably a better way

Answer (score 2):

You need two locks.  The one used inside your `func()`, and one to protect the process's signal mask.

You have to make masking and unmasking the signal atomic also:

```
static  pthread_mutex_t mask_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sigset_t old_set;
sigset_t new_set;

sigemptyset( &new_set );
sigaddset( &new_set, SIGINT );

pthread_mutex_lock( &mask_mutex );

pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_mask, &old_mask );

func();

pthread_sigmask( SIG_SETMASK, &old_mask, NULL );

pthread_mutex_unlock( &mask_mutex );
```

With no lock around the `pthread_sigmask()`, threads are likely to corrupt the process sigmask as execution overlaps.

Comment: What if a signal is called before pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &new_mask, &old_mask ), and after pthread_mutex_lock( &mask_mutex )? Then we'd have a deadlock, right? What if we switched the operations order?

Comment: @falhumai No, because it's not the same mutex.  If a signal is delivered after the mutex protecting the `pthread_sigmask()` calls is locked, the thread that locked that mutex *can not hold the mutex in `func()` yet.*  Between the two `pthread_sigmask()` calls, `func()` is *de facto* not a signal handler and can therefore be called safely.  The second mutex is needed to protect the `pthread_sigmask()` calls and maintain a consistent signal mask for the process.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the *test mutex* functions (trylock) in this kind of undefined situations, to be safe. And with this, you don't necessarily need to block too.