# Are pthread_sigmask inner operations atomic?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, atomic

Referring to a question I raised weeks ago here ([Is there a way to ensure atomicity while having a multithreaded program with signal handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313916/is-there-a-way-to-ensure-atomicity-while-having-a-multithreaded-program-with-sig/38314927?noredirect=1)), and regarding one of its main answers or comments, as the title states, are pthread_sigmask operations atomic themselves, or they require locks such as mutexes? I just want to be sure.

Comment: `pthread_sigmask()` is not on the list of thread-unsafe functions in POSIX here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/threads.html. This is not particularly surprising, since the call only modifies the calling thread's signal-mask, so there is no reason why another thread calling the function should interfere with it.

Comment: Great!! That is what I was REALLY looking for.